# Rollup для запроса с union

Tags: mysql

Есть необходимость подсчитать сумму всех строк. Запрос с union, в данный момент я считаю итоги для каждого селекта. Вопрос, как посчитать общие итоги и вывести только одну эту строку?

```
    SELECT order_delivery_data.order_delivery_data_name,
sum(round(case `order`.order_status when 'paid' then `order`.order_totalSumm else 0 end)) paid,
sum(round(case `order`.order_status when 'later' then `order`.order_totalSumm else 0 end)) later
FROM order_delivery_data
INNER JOIN `order` ON order_delivery_data.order_id = `order`.order_id
WHERE
   order_delivery_data.order_delivery_data_name in ('BetaPost','Pony Express Россия','Доставка Почтой России',
'КСЭ','Москва BetaPro','СДЭК','СПСР')
GROUP BY order_delivery_data.order_delivery_data_name WITH ROLLUP
UNION 
   select IFNULL(`delivery-types`.`delivery-types_name`,'Total'),
sum(round(case `order`.order_status when 'paid' then `order`.order_totalSumm else 0 end)) paid,
sum(round(case `order`.order_status when 'later' then `order`.order_totalSumm else 0 end)) later
FROM `delivery-types`

INNER JOIN order_delivery ON `delivery-types`.`delivery-types_code` = order_delivery.order_delivery_code
INNER JOIN `order` ON order_delivery.order_id = `order`.order_id
WHERE order_delivery.order_delivery_code = 'courier'

GROUP BY `delivery-types`.`delivery-types_name` WITH ROLLUP
```

Comment: `select нужные-суммы from (ваш-текущий-запрос-без-rollup) X`

Comment: @Mike можно пример, не совсем понял.

Comment: А что означает ваше "вывести только эту строку", т.е. вам разбиение по  типам не нужно ? тогда вообще в запросе можно убрать все group by и выбрать `select sum(paid), sum(later) from (ваш-запрос) X`

Comment: @Mike спасибо.разобрался